# How to add new column in SSIS Package. When the columns are at max?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have a package with 600 columns, and now I need to add a new column to the package. But SSIS is telling me that I reached the maximum limit of columns. Is there any way I can add the new column?

Comment: Before thinking about how to add a new column, you should think about why you have 600 columns in a single package!! Please provide more information about the package (ETL job) you are designing and the data source so you can get better support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before thinking about adding a new column, you should think about **why you have 600 columns in a single package!!**

When working with a data source with a considerable number of data columns, you should ignore the useless columns or merge them into one **Jumbo** column (comma-separated values, JSON, XML...).

### Example 1 - Flat File

In case that your data source is a flat file and that only the first few columns are useful, you can go to the *Flat File Connection Manager > Advanced Tab* and minimize the number of columns.

[image]

### Example 2 - SQL Server source

If your data source is an SQL database, you can customize the columns you need to merge using functions like `CONCAT_WS()` *(Concatenate with separator)*. As an example:

```sql
SELECT [Co1], [Col2], [Col5], CONCAT_WS(';',[Col3],[Col4],[Col6]) as [Jumbo1], CONCAT_WS(';',[Col7],[Col8],[Col9]) as [Jumbo2]
FROM MyTable
```

**Side IMPORTANT note:** If you use an OLE DB source, do not ignore columns by unchecking them from the OLE DB Source editor. Use a SQL command instead. I highly suggest reading the following articles:

- [SSIS OLE DB Source: SQL Command vs. Table or View](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-ole-db-source-sql-command-vs-table-or-view/)
- [Data Access Modes in SSIS OLE DB Destination: SQL Command vs. Table or View](https://www.sqlshack.com/data-access-modes-in-ssis-ole-db-destination-sql-command-vs-table-or-view/)

### Similar Issues

- [Is there a limit in the number of columns in a dataflow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/250d0c32-6e4a-414d-8594-044f943eb468/is-there-a-limit-in-number-of-columns-in-a-dataflow?forum=sqlintegrationservices)